# There are two PSW switches on this motherboard. What are they for?

Tags: boot, bios, motherboard, switch, cmos

Im checking out the motherboard on an Asus Vivo AiO (all-in-one) computer. The computer model is: m241. The motherboard model is: V241DA.

Originally, I'm having an issue viewing BIOS, POST, Advanced pre-boot menus, etc... From an external monitor, since the internal LCD is damaged and gone.

Here's an attached image. I see two switches labeled as PSW1 and PSW2. What are these?

The official manual does not talk about the motherboard, and I can't find a schematic.

[image]

Comment: You don't generally need a manual -for things like this.You need a *service* manual, which a lot of manufacturers don't provide. Dumb question - are these switches accessible externally and do they correspond to anything if they do?

Comment: Something is soldered to them, so you should be able to figure out what they do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.